# "ENOTDIR invalid cwd" when running a new Jupyter notebook on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Recently, when I create a new Jupyter Notebook, I have an error "ENOTDIR invalid cwd" on Visual Studio Code and I cannot run cells in that notebook. This error does not happen when I use old Jypyter notebooks or if I duplicate an old Jupyter Notebook and run a cell in it. Does anybody know how to fix this error?

You can see the error on the bottom right corner of the image below.
[image: You can see the error on the bottom right corner.]
It's strange that python's version is not written on the upper left corner while for old notebooks, it is shown as can be seen below.[image]

Here are the contents of my main "settings.json":

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "~/anaconda3/bin/python",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "debug.onTaskErrors": "showErrors",
    "python.dataScience.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "python.dataScience.widgetScriptSources": [
        "jsdelivr.com",
        "unpkg.com"
    ],
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false
}
```

"settings.json" of the workspace is empty and here are the contents of "launch.json" of the workspace:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How did you create Jupyter in VSCode? Have you selected the Python interpreter and installed the dependency package "ipykernel" required by Jupyter?

Comment: I installed Anaconda3 and it says 'requirement is already satisfied" when I try to run "pip install ipykernel".

Comment: Have you tried using other Python interpreters? Could you provide us with relevant screenshots so that we can check other related factors? (Please overwrite your user name and other personal information)

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot of the error message. I am on Linux so I have the system's python interpreter but I cannot run Jupiter notebooks with it.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Do you have any settings related to "cwd" in the "launch.json" file? And does it contain related settings in "settings.json"? It is recommended that you comment out the relevant "cwd" settings and reload VSCode.

Comment: I added the information on "settings.json" and "launch.json" to the question. They don't seem to contain any settings on "cwd".

Comment: -I can create a Jupyter file in VSCode using the setting information you provided. Since the Jupyter function in VSCode is provided by the Python extension, you could try to reinstall it or use another version of the Python extension.

Comment: I reinstalled the python extension on VSCode but it didn't solve the issue. I can still execute notebooks created before the error started appearing but I cannot execute notebooks that are created after that.

Comment: Could you create ".ipynb" files manually? And have you tried to create Jupyter files in a global environment or a [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments) in VSCode?

Comment: I tried creating Jupyter files manually in a global environment (base).

Comment: I noticed that for the notebooks that are running without the error, python's version is shown in the upper right corner. You can see it in the second image of the question. It's not the case for those that have the error.

Comment: Yes, when the kernel and related dependencies cannot be successfully connected, the Python interpreter will not be displayed in the upper right corner of Jupyter. In addition, what is the version number of the module named "traitlets" in your current environment? There is a version incompatibility that will cause it to fail to load when created, so please try to use "traitlets==4.3.3".

Comment: Yes, the version of "traitlets" is 4.3.3

Comment: You can try to create a new environment and reinstall "ipykernel".